# Use function everywhere without writing it more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get my code cleaner I don't want to write the same code many times but don't know how to accomplish it. You can see in the code below is the `if/else` written twice but doing the same. How can I `return` data and call that function again with writing it only once?

Help and advices are much appreciated.

Code is like this:

```
(function($){
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var header = $('header');
    var headerSmall = header.children('.small');
    var headerBigWrap = header.children('.big');
    var headerBigWrapHeight = headerBigWrap.height();

    var showNav = function() {
        header.css('position','fixed');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','none');
        headerSmall.css('display','block');
    }

    var hideNav = function() {
        header.css('position','static');
        headerSmall.css('display','none');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','block');
    }

    // don't want to write this more than once 
    // but need to call here on document ready
    if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
        showNav();
    } else {
        hideNav();
    }


    $(window).scroll(function(event){

        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        // here I need it again
        // scroll is changing on scroll
        // but "function" does exactly the same like above

        if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
            showNav();
        } else {
            hideNav();
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

if you need html and css working example: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cejs3jhs/  and rest of code:

```
<header>
    <div class="big">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <span class="icon nav-icon">Nav Icon</span>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="page"></div>

<style type="text/css">
header {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0.5;
}
header.toggle-nav {
    height:100%;
}
header.toggle-nav ul {
    display:block;
}
header > div {
    position:relative;
    width:976px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header > div.big {
    padding:30px 0;
}
.page {
    height:5000px;
    background-color:orange;
    opacity:0.5;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simply what Justinas said, make another function. But you can improve a bit with some more aggressive editing, which is what I've done.

```
(function ($) {
    var header = $('header');
    var headerSmall = header.children('.small');
    var headerBigWrap = header.children('.big');
    var headerBigWrapHeight = headerBigWrap.height();

    function setNavStyle() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
            header.css('position', 'fixed');
            headerSmall.css('display', 'block');
            headerBigWrap.css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            header.css('position', 'static');
            headerSmall.css('display', 'none');
            headerBigWrap.css('display', 'block');
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(setNavStyle);
    setNavStyle();
})(jQuery);
```

That's one way, but it would be better (more maintainable, simpler, faster) to do the bulk of
the work with CSS, like so:

CSS:

```
header {
    position: static;
}
header>.small {
    display: none;
}
header>.big {
    display: block;
}

.stickyNav header {
    position: fixed;
}
.stickyNav header>.small {
    display: block;
}
.stickyNav header>.big {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    var bigNavHeight = $('header>.big').height();
    function setNavStyle() {
        var bigIsOffscreen = $(this).scrollTop() >= bigNavHeight;

        $(document.body).toggleClass('stickyNav', bigIsOffscreen);
    }

    $(window).scroll(setNavStyle);
    setNavStyle();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: wow, this is what I was looking for, the seccond part of your answer! how to call `setNavStyle()` on document ready? cause if I call it like usual I get `setNavStyle is not defined`

Comment: The code I posted already calls it as it's being declared. If that's not when you want to call it, then you should just declare the function properly then reference it twice. ie, `function setNavStyle() {[...]}; $(window).scroll(setNavStyle); $(document).ready(setNavStyle);`.

Comment: how is `stickyNav` class added to body on page load if we already scrolled down the page? I thought `$(window).scroll()` only gets called after a "real" scroll ..

Comment: @caramba You were right about that. But notice that I added `()` after the `setNavStyle` declaration, and a return line that returns the function itself. This causes it to be invoked, then pass the function's return value (which is the function itself) to `$.scroll`.

If it's still confusing, I can just edit it to a more standard and slightly more verbose style.

Comment: :) it is still a bit confusing. It is exactly what I want but I don't get it. After the function is "invoked" it gets called on page load? why?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and edit and time @Tristan

Comment: @caramba My pleasure :) I've edited the answer because I probably shouldn't have tried to be so clever - as they say, the best code is obvious code. But to try to explain it to you, I created a simplified jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/6au4f51g/. In the fiddle, `callFunction` is replacing `$.scroll`, and `alert1` replacing `setNavStyle`. Notice that `alert1` is called twice.

Comment: sorry @Tristan, in the new (I thought soo simple fiddle, 5 lines of code..) but what is going on there? could you write some comments in there. I still don't get it: you created the function callFunction but fn(); does nothing!? or what get's declared there? anyway, I'll ask a new question soon to ask what's going on there and will post the link also here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62995/discussion-between-tristan-berger-and-caramba).

Answer (score 2):

So just make separate function for that:

```
function showHideNav(scroll, headerBigWrapHeight, element) {
    var scroll = element.scrollTop(),
    header = $('header'),
    headerSmall = header.children('.small'),
    headerBigWrap = header.children('.big')
    headerBigWrapHeight = headerBigWrap.height();

    if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
        header.css('position','fixed');
    } else {
        header.css('position','static');
    }

    headerBigWrap.toggle();
    headerSmall.toggle();
}

(function($){
    showHideNav(scroll);

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        showHideNav(scroll);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new function just as you did with the showNav & hideNav functions

```
(function($){
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var header = $('header');
    var headerSmall = header.children('.small');
    var headerBigWrap = header.children('.big');
    var headerBigWrapHeight = headerBigWrap.height();

    var showNav = function() {
        header.css('position','fixed');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','none');
        headerSmall.css('display','block');
    }

    var hideNav = function() {
        header.css('position','static');
        headerSmall.css('display','none');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','block');
    }

     var checkScroll = function (scroll,headerBigWrapHeight){
    if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
        showNav();
    } else {
        hideNav();
    }

    checkScroll(scroll,headerBigWrapHeight);


    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
         checkScroll(scroll,headerBigWrapHeight);
    });



})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below updated JS code:

```
(function($){
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var header = $('header');
    var headerSmall = header.children('.small');
    var headerBigWrap = header.children('.big');
    var headerBigWrapHeight = headerBigWrap.height();

    var showNav = function() {
        header.css('position','fixed');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','none');
        headerSmall.css('display','block');
    }

    var hideNav = function() {
        header.css('position','static');
        headerSmall.css('display','none');
        headerBigWrap.css('display','block');
    }

    var callFun = function(scroll) {
        if( scroll >= headerBigWrapHeight ) {
            showNav();
        } else {
            hideNav();
        }
    }


    callFun(scroll);


    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        callFun(scroll);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you, but like another user explained (unfortunaletly removed hes answer) we don't even have to pass the parameter `scroll` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Do it exactly like you have done with functions `showNav` and `hideNav`: define a function with `if/else` inside somewhere and you can call it by name wherever needed. There are also some variables which can be omitted then, so I show all code here:

```
(function($){
    // var scroll is moved into function scrollFunc
    var header = $('header');
    var headerSmall = header.children('.small');
    var headerBigWrap = header.children('.big');
    // var headerBigWrap is moved into function scrollFunc

    var showNav = function() {
        /* your code */
    }

    var hideNav = function() {
        /* your code */
    }

    var scrollFunc = function () {
        if($(this).scroll() >= headerBigWrap.height() ) {
            showNav();
        } else {
            hideNav();
        }
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        scrollFunc();
    });

    scrollFunc(); // call it first time to initialize

});
```

Comment: thank you but it also works without changing my vars, as one user explained but removed hes answer.